# Evaluating Sigma Notation Summation

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

[image]

Given to two sums at the top, how am I supposed to calculate the following 5 problems? I've tried splitting sigma notation where possible but I still cant figure it out, any hints?

I have completed problems 1 and 2 but any assistance on problems 3, 4 and 5 would be appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you write out each term in the first few problems, cancel and group terms appropriately, to see how this works.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork so for problem 1, isnt it essentially the sum of the two sigmas given? I wrote it out and noticed $j-2$  is equivalent to the $i=1 to 10$ sum and $j+8$ equivalent to the second sigma from $i=11 to 20$. is this correct?

Comment: I solved problem 1! now for the rest of the problems!

Comment: Yep.  Now keep going...

Comment: solved problem 2! going to leave problem 3 for now since I dont know what a floor function is..

Comment: Look up Floor:  $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $x$.  Examples:  $\lfloor 2.3 \rfloor = 2$, $\lfloor 9.7\rfloor = 9$, $\lfloor -3.2 \rfloor = -4$, etc.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance @DavidG.Stork .I have to attend to other matters before I try to solve anymore of these so any other hints for problems 3, 4 and 5 would be of great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try these:
3.
$$\sum_{k=2}^{21} a_{k-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{20} a_{k}$$
$$\sum_{k=2}^{21} a_{\lfloor k/2\rfloor} = \sum_{k=2,4,...,20} a_{\lfloor k/2\rfloor} + \sum_{k=3,5,...,21} a_{\lfloor k/2\rfloor} = \sum_{k=1}^{10} a_{k} + \sum_{k=1}^{10} a_{k}$$

4.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}a_{2i} + \sum_{i=1}^{10}a_{2i-1} = \sum_{i=1}^{20}a_{i}$$

5.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}(i+a_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{10} i + \sum_{i=1}^{10} a_i$$
and
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10} i = \frac{(1+10)10}{2}$$